# xliffmerge with angular what does profile.json contain

Tags: angular, internationalization, xliff

im followin the instruction in

https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport

after running "extract-i18n": "ng xi18n --output-path src/assets/locale && xliffmerge --profile src/assets/locale/mergConfig.json --verbose" I get this :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcDir' of undefined
    at XliffMergeParameters.readProfile (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge-parameters.js:115:96)
    at XliffMergeParameters.configure (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge-parameters.js:63:35)
    at Function.createFromOptions (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge-parameters.js:24:20)
    at XliffMerge.runAsync (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge.js:127:77)
    at XliffMerge.run (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge.js:104:14)
    at Function.main (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/xliff-merge.js:26:89)
    at Object. (/home/Alternant/Angular/I18n_ng-showcase/webapp/node_modules/@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport/src/xliffmerge/main.js:8:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! NgShowCase@19.1.0 extract-i18n: `ng xi18n --output-path src/assets/locale && xliffmerge --profile src/assets/locale/fr.json --verbose`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the NgShowCase@19.1.0 extract-i18n script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/Alternant/.npm/_logs/2020-02-17T15_02_30_563Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

what does mergeConfig.json file contains?(empty json rightnow)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your mergConfig.json is found and srcDir is pointing to an existing folder.

My configuration file (xliffmerge.json) is in the same folder as package.json with the following content:

```
{
  "xliffmergeOptions": {
    "srcDir": "src/i18n",
    "genDir": "src/i18n",
    "defaultLanguage": "en",
    "allowIdChange": true
  }
}
```

And this is my extract-i18n command in package.json:

```
"extract-i18n": "ng xi18n --output-path i18n && xliffmerge --profile xliffmerge.json da en",
```

I am using Angular 10.